# Spring JPA - Query Methods

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have this table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_tropical",
        uniqueConstraints =
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
                "name",
                "sign",
                "isRetro",
                "house",
                "lang"}))
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
public class Tropical {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String sign;
    private Boolean isRetro;
    private Integer house;
    private String lang;
    private Date updateDate;
    
}
```

and this method:

```
@Repository
public interface TropicalRepository extends JpaRepository<Tropical, Long> {

    Tropical findByHouseIsAndSignAndIsRetroAndLangIs
            (Integer house, String sign, Boolean retro, String lang);

}
```

but does not seems to work. I found for existing house / sign / isRetro and land and return null

Comment: "does not seems to work": please describe what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: What are the parameters you supplied? What is the SQL executed? What got bound to it? What does the entity/data row look like that you expect to find?

Comment: Well, my answer was supposed to make you learn, so next time you get it right yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct query should look as follows using the JPA naming conventions:

```
@Repository
public interface TropicalRepository extends JpaRepository<Tropical, Long> {

    Tropical findByHouseAndSignAndIsRetroAndLang
            (Integer house, String sign, Boolean retro, String lang);

}
```

In your query there seemed to be an `Is` appended to `House` and to `Lang`. These cannot be resolved based on the attributes in your entity.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are following spring Data JPA naming conventions as documented here: [spring-data-derived-queries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords).

In your example you seem not to follow those